# How to vertically align DIV with an image

Tags: html, css

I have an issue that i noticed is very popular. Despite all the examples i didn't find a solution that works for me.

Here is what i have http://jsfiddle.net/yeLqN/

```
<div id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png">
            <div id="hot">
                <h1>test</h1>
                <h3>Test</h3>

            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is live version with images http://minecraft-adventure.com/test/
So what i want to do is center the hot div with the img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the image center  just make the `image` as a `block level` element . Here is modified CSS.

```
#logo img{display:block; vertical-align:top;}
```

Here is the Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/yeLqN/7/

Comment: Ok maybe i did a bad job at explaining the issue... Here is what i want the result to look like http://imageshack.com/a/img545/5789/crok.png I want the HOT DIV to be centered with the IMG, the image does not move the div does

Comment: now I've added the `height` to <img> tag. can you please check the update Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/yeLqN/15/

Comment: if u change the img height to lets say 300px u can see that the div is not centered.

Comment: Hi now the div is aligned vertically, can you please check the Demo.
http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/yeLqN/42/

Comment: If this is you are looking for and if its solve your problem. then accept this answer so this discussion could be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that you just want to center it with the image, you can use margin-top to achieve this

Comment: When i apply margin to the hot div it moves the image as well

Comment: And applying float:left to both of them? and then the margin

Answer (score 0):

Use image as css background and set position to center:

```
background: url('images/logo.png') center center no-repeat;
display: block;
height: 150px;
width: 200px;
float: left;
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeLqN/9/)

OR
just set alignment for `img`, what will be easy especially if you do know the height of line:

```
height: 50px;
margin: 50px 20px 50px 20px;
```

Comment: Seems you don't quite understand my issue here :) I want the right hot div to be vertically centered with the image. What u did does not do that

Comment: ann.. ok! so look this link: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/. Basically, it will be easy if you have a predefined height for DIV and IMG, so you would just need to set css margins in div.